# Is it safe or normal to close/cover junction boxes but use existing line to power new boxes just a few (6-12) inches away from the old ones?

Tags: electrical, wiring, attic, ceiling-fan

We have 2 pendant lights hanging over a breakfast bar in the kitchen. The boxes are easily accessible in the attic. We'd like to move them back a few inches and then add additional wiring for a 3rd box/light. Electrician wants to close/cover the 2 existing boxes, add 3 new ones in a row and use existing line to power the new. Keeping in mind the 2 existing ones could be moved back - creating slack in the line - before adding a few feet for the 3rd/new light,  why not just do that? Thanks much. [image: here is a picture of the first of the 2 boxes in the attic]

Comment: There are reasoning not to patch and paint, but that is _your_ call, not the electricians.

Comment: If you're only going to use these boxes as junction boxes from now on, you'll have to flip them around so you can access the wiring inside from the attic

Comment: I talked to the electrician. The boxes are going to be capped and flipped around.

Answer (score 3):

There's no technical reason that he can't move the boxes. It would certainly be more elegant.

My best guess is that your electrician doesn't like drywall repair/ painting. If the ceiling is textured, that's a strong disincentive, as matching texture is hard.

He'll definitely save you money with his approach.

Comment: I agree with you 100% about moving the lights and patching the holes, it would look a lot better then just covering them.

Answer (score 2):

The old boxes in their current location will be decommissioned. Whether they get caps, or are removed and the holes patched over is an aesthetic question and up to you (as @Kris says).

Since you have access from the attic, you have two choices as expressed in your question

- leave existing wire and boxes connected, shift them, and add wiring and a third box
- remove old boxes and connecting wiring, put in three new boxes, use existing feed wire to first box, and wire between the next two.

This is a question of which is faster based on ease of access. The cost of new boxes and wires is negligible compared to electricians hourly rate. Often it makes more sense to leave old stuff in place, patch over and add new, cheap stuff.  And this is independent of whether the old box holes get covers or patched.